# Facebook OG Image If, or, or, else statement

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have 3 sources of image which users can contribute to. Either with a instagram URL, an image URL or with an image upload. Users can only choose to contribute using 1 out of any of the 3.

I am trying to help Facebook OpenGraph extract image from either the instagram source / the image url / the image upload. The embedded instagram image, I have it as a custom field already, but not the image url though. And if none of these 3 have been provided by user, the icon of the site will turn up.

I know how to include the image upload, but I'm not sure how I should include the instagram image (custom fielded) and image url, can someone help me?

I have this code:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_fb_open_graph_tags');
function add_fb_open_graph_tags() {
if (is_single()) {
    global $post;
    if(get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail')) {
        $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
        $thumbnail_object = get_post($thumbnail_id);
        $image = $thumbnail_object->guid;
    } else {    
        $image = 'http://my-site.com/wp-content/themes/something/images/icon.jpg'; // Change this to the URL of the logo you want beside your links shown on Facebook
    }

 ?>
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description ?>" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" />

<?php   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple `og:image` tags to your markup to allow Facebook to pick-up any additional images you want to use:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />
```

Try adding the instagram image and uploaded image in this way.